# What is the difference between TFT LCD driver and TFT LCD controller

Tags: touch, display, lcd

i have selected two displays
1) https://www.buydisplay.com/default/lcd-5-ssd1963-tft-module-touch-screen-display-800x480-mcu-arduino
2)https://www.buydisplay.com/default/5-tft-lcd-display-module-wvga-800x480-high-resolution-for-mp4-gps

the first one display contains controller board and second one do not have that controller, also the second one have driver IC ILI6122

datasheets can be found from the above links for reference

i want to know the purpose and effects of pins (1)CS# (2)D/C# (3)E(Rd) (4)R/W# in the display with controller and why these pins are not in the display mentioned in second link?

Answer (score 1):

CS - Chip Select
D/C - Data/Command
E - Enable
R/W - Read/Write

To help with understanding the above four pins check out this link
https://electronicsforu.com/resources/learn-electronics/16x2-lcd-pinout-diagram